# Extract object from rails dropdown and pass value to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, mapbox, ruby-on-rails-6

I am creating a mini navigation app and I have 2 models (Location, Path) with the following details

Location

- id:integer
- Name:string
- Latitude:decimal {:precision => 8, :scale => 4}
- longitude:decimal {:precision => 8, :scale => 4}

Path

- start:integer
- end:integer

On the form to create a path I have 2 drop downs which are populated from the list of locations

```
<div class="field">
    <%= form.label :start %>
    <%= collection_select(:path, :start, Location.all, :id, :Name, prompt: true) %>
</div>

<div class="field">
    <%= form.label :end %>
    <%= collection_select(:path, :end, Location.all, :id, :Name, prompt: true) %>
</div>
```

Below this I want to add a map using MapBox and display a marker for the start and end locations, previously I have used the below code to pass data from my controller to the view and allow it to be accessed by the JQuery that generates the map

```
<%= content_tag :div, class: "temp_information", data: {lat: @location.Latitude,long: @location.Longitude} do %>
<% end %>

<script>
map code
$('.temp_information').data('lat')
$('.temp_information').data('long')
</script>
```

How can I extract the Latitude & Longitude from each of the selected locations and make it available to javascript?

EDIT - Added code for Path form

```
<%= form_with(model: path, local: true) do |form| %>
<% if path.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(path.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this path from being saved:</h2>

    <ul>
        <% path.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
    </div>
<% end %>

<div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :start %>
    <%= form.select :start_id, options_for_select(Location.all.map{ |l| [l.Name, form.object.start_id, { data: { latitude: l.Latitude, longitude: l.Longitude } }] }), { prompt: true }, { class: "form-control" } %> 
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :end %>
    <%= form.select :finish_id, options_for_select(Location.all.map{ |l| [l.Name, form.object.finish_id, { data: { latitude: l.Latitude, longitude: l.Longitude } }] }), { prompt: true }, { class: "form-control" } %>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :minutes %>
    <%= form.number_field :minutes, class: "form-control" %>
</div>

<div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use [gon gem](https://github.com/gazay/gon) for passing data from ruby to javascript.

I have written such code:

```rb
# 20190718113356_create_locations.rb
class CreateLocations < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :locations do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.decimal :latitude, precision: 10, scale: 6
      t.decimal :longitude, precision: 10, scale: 6

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
# 20190718113423_create_paths.rb
class CreatePaths < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :paths do |t|
      t.references :start, index: true, foreign_key: { to_table: :locations }
      t.references :finish, index: true, foreign_key: { to_table: :locations }

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
# location.rb
class Location < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :start_paths, class_name: 'Path', foreign_key: 'start_id', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :finish_paths, class_name: 'Path', foreign_key: 'finish_id', dependent: :destroy

  validates :name, :latitude, :longitude, presence: true
end
```

```rb
# path.rb
class Path < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :start, class_name: 'Location', foreign_key: 'start_id'
  belongs_to :finish, class_name: 'Location', foreign_key: 'finish_id'

  validates :start, :finish, presence: true
end
```

```rb
# seeds.rb
Location.destroy_all

10.times do |t|
  Location.create!(
    name: SecureRandom.uuid,
    latitude: rand(-90.000000000...90.000000000),
    longitude: rand(-180.000000000...180.000000000)
  )
end


15.times do |t|
  Path.create!(
    start: Location.order("RANDOM()").first,
    finish: Location.order("RANDOM()").first
  )
end
```

I select lat and long for all paths in controller:

```rb
gon.paths = Path.all.preload(:start, :finish).map{ |p| {start: { latitude: p.start.latitude, longitude: p.finish.latitude }, finish: { latitude: p.start.latitude, longitude: p.finish.latitude } } }
p = Path.first
gon.path = {start: { latitude: p.start.latitude, longitude: p.finish.latitude }, finish: { latitude: p.start.latitude, longitude: p.finish.latitude } }
```

And show paths in javascript

```
alert(JSON.stringify(gon.paths))
alert(JSON.stringify(gon.path))
```

How to find data in javascript

```
<%= form_for Path.new, url: '' do |form| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :start_id %>
    <%= form.select :start_id, options_for_select(Location.all.map{ |l| [l.name, l.id, { data: { latitude: l.latitude, longitude: l.longitude } }] }), { selected: form.object.start_id, prompt: true }, { class: 'startSelect' } %>
  </div>
  <br /><br />
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :end_id %>
    <%= form.select :finish_id, options_for_select(Location.all.map{ |l| [l.name, l.id, { data: { latitude: l.latitude, longitude: l.longitude } }] }), { selected: form.object.finish_id, prompt: true }, { class: 'endSelect' } %>
  </div>
<% end %>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $(".startSelect").change(function() {
      alert(JSON.stringify(['startSelect changed', { latitude: $(this).find(':selected').data('latitude'), longitude: $(this).find(':selected').data('longitude') }]));
    });

    $(".endSelect").change(function() {
      alert(JSON.stringify(['endSelect changed', { latitude: $(this).find(':selected').data('latitude'), longitude: $(this).find(':selected').data('longitude') }]));
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Quick question, I'm getting the following error when I try and create a path 'Start must exist
Start can't be blank'

Comment: Could you please share example of code in which you create Path?

Comment: I've added this in the question

Comment: I have updated answer (I changed <%= form.select...). Please try and see if it works.

Comment: Still gives the same error if it helps the rails server logs say the following 
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"M0wWTywgDRmT4HyqrfOBD7ldS6l+47uSWnviEm/UkfphkMZmolGfU0cSPgkVTz8mPUtIGLMU4XnHQoh3V/gd/g==", "path"=>{"start_id"=>"6", "finish_id"=>"6", "minutes"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create Path"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]

Unpermitted parameters: :start_id, :finish_id

Comment: `def create @path = Path.new(path_params) ...`
`def path_params params.require(:path).permit(:start_id, :finish_id) end`

https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters

Comment: Ahh, forgot I'd need to update the controller to allow start_id and end_id. that works great now thank you